# Classic page Close Button and Stop Editing Button redirect another page, need to change redirect URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, 2019, site, classic-experience

when I click on the Close button Stop Editing Button at the top of the site page in SP2019, it should redirect me to another link that I don't want to go to.

I want to change the redirect page URL.

I mentioned an image below, where I am clicking.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Can you explain your requirements in detail? By default, when you click on "Stop Editing" button, SharePoint will open the same page in "view" mode (from edit mode). So, what exactly you need here now?

Comment: I have to add a new page URL and modify the default URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the current page link to the redirection, SP2019 provides you with an option to avoid going to a specific page. By default, SharePoint opens the same page in "view" mode (as opposed to edit mode) when you click the Stop Editing button and Close button.

You must include a parameter in the Page link provided in the example below if you wish to navigate to a specific page.

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Dashboard_Dev.aspx?Source=page-Link-Where-you-wish-to-navigate